# Losing data on post when using EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

The Problem:

When I submit the form I am losing any information entered into the edit templates for the addresses.

I have the following model:

```
public class MoveRecord
{
    public Address StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Address EndPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Where Address is defined as:

```
public class Address
{
    public String City { get; set;}
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Line1{ get; set; }
    public String PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MoveRecord model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Save info
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

My edit view uses:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Move", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartPoint);
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndPoint);
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

My edit template is:

```
<table class="form address">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 200px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Line1):
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Line1, new { style = "width: 300px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="zip">
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostalCode):
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="city">
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City):
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="state">
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StateProvince):
            </th>
            <td> 
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StateProvince, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything renders just fine, however when I submit the form the model that I get in the action method does not contain any information entered into the address field. If I move everything into the same view then it works just fine but what I would like is to be able to use the editor templates to keep my views easy to read. **How can I get the data from the editor template correctly bound to the model?**

Edit: Posted my action method

Comment: What does your Action method signature look like?

Comment: I added my Action method to my original question

Answer (score 0):

The action you are submitting the form to must look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MoveRecord model)
{
    // model.StartPoint and model.EndPoint should be correctly bound here.
    ...
}
```

Or if you are trying to bind directly to the two addresses you need to set the correct prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(
    [Bind(Prefix = "StartPoint")] Address start, 
    [Bind(Prefix = "EndPoint")] Address end
)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the first answer?  How do you correctly bind?